# In my Custom Listview Android ==> Null Pointer Exception..?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I am new to Android and Java,
Please help me this makes me crazy for 2days.
What wrong in my code.

When I run the code it shows "Unfortunately the (**program**) has stopped.

I try to find out in debug mode. I see Null Pointer Exception.

The point is I don't know where is the error.

---

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<Food> arrayList = new ArrayList<Food>();
    Food f1 = new Food("COKE", 1, 1, 1);
    Food f2 = new Food("PEPSI", 2, 2, 2);
    Food f3 = new Food("Pizza", 3, 3, 2);
    Food f4 = new Food("Sprite", 4, 4, 2);

    arrayList.add(f1);
    arrayList.add(f2);
    arrayList.add(f3);
    arrayList.add(f4);

    FoodAdapter fa = new FoodAdapter(this, R.layout.food_row, arrayList);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setAdapter(fa);

}
```

---

FoodAdapter.Java

```
public class FoodAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Food> {
private Context context;
private int resourceId;
private ArrayList<Food> objects = new ArrayList<Food> ();

public FoodAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Food>  objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

    this.context = context;
    this.resourceId = textViewResourceId;
    this.objects = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = null;
    FoodHolder holder = null;
    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater =( (Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        v = inflater.inflate(resourceId, null);  

        holder.Name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.FoodId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.SubId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        v.setTag(holder);

    }else{
        holder = (FoodHolder)v.getTag();
    }
    Food food = objects.get(position);
    holder.FoodId.setText(food.FoodId);
    holder.Name.setText(food.Name);
    holder.SubId.setText(food.SubId);

    return v;
}

static class FoodHolder{
    TextView Name;
    TextView FoodId;
    TextView SubId;
}
```

}

---

Food.Java

```
public class Food{
public Food(String name, int foodId, int subId, int productMode) {
    super();
    Name = name;
    FoodId = foodId;
    SubId = subId;
    ProductMode = productMode;
}
public String Name;
public int FoodId;
public int SubId;
public int ProductMode;
```

}

**Edit:**

logcat trace

```
  04-20 00:47:56.785: W/ResourceType(1486): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001
04-20 00:47:56.785: D/AndroidRuntime(1486): Shutting down VM
04-20 00:47:56.785: W/dalvikvm(1486): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:247)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3428)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at com.example.testconcept.FoodAdapter.getView(FoodAdapter.java:50)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1863)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11180)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4203)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11180)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4203)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11180)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4203)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11180)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4203)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1468)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2418)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-20 00:47:56.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the logcat output of the crash.

Comment: The `objects` variable is really unnecessary with the `ArrayAdapter`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't instantiate your Holder

```
if(convertView==null){

    holder =new FoodHolder();
     ..
     ..

}
```

**Edit:**

second issue is that

> you are assigning int values to your TextView's in GetView, which it will think as string resource id

So it will throw String resource not found Exception

Try to set them like this

```
 holder.FoodId.setText(String.valueOf(food.FoodId));
 holder.Name.setText(food.Name);
 holder.SubId.setText(String.valueOf(food.SubId));
```

Comment: It doesn't work. right now i Got " ressource not found". Thank you for fast reply, @Pragnani

Comment: @riseres "it doesn't work" in the sense? This will cause Exception as your holder is is null. i.e remove type before holder as I have edited my answer..Also post your logcat if it doens't work

Comment: I added catlog in answer section. @Pragnani

Comment: @riseres Have you tried my Latest edit..? Don't post it as new answer delete that and edit your question instead.

Comment: @riseres I have already posted answer for the above mentioned Exception in my edit, check that..

Comment: The Problem solved.  thank you very very much. So i can do my project  @Pragnani

Answer (score 0):

initialize and use it in this manner ,

```
ViewHolder holder;              
if (convertView == null) 
{
   holder = new ViewHolder();
   holder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_text);                   
   rowView.setTag(holder);
} 
else
{
    rowView = convertView;
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
}
```